# Value of a function, kdb+

Tags: kdb

I have a contrived function:

```
q)f:{a:6;b:2;c::5}
```

When I use `value` on it I get the following list:

```
q)value f
0xa0030902a1030a02a20b0481000004
,`x
`a`b
``c
6
2
5
5 0 4 0 9 0 8 0 14 0 12 0 12 2 2
"..f"
""
-1
"{a:6;b:2;c::5}"
```

I know what all items mean except items at index 0, 7, 8, 9 and 10.

I assume item 0 is a GUID assigned to the function by the interpreter to uniquely identify the function, (across time and space! ;) ).

Item 7 may be to with order of interpretation of the other indexes but 12 and 14 don't make sense under this assumption.

I assume item 8 is just the functions name, though why the `..`?

Any insights into those listed indexes would be appreciated, thank-you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lambda reference on the kx website explains each part of the output https://code.kx.com/q/ref/value/#lambda